# "Art" countable or uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

I am developing a position titled "Fine **Art** Registrar/ Fine **Arts** Registrar"

I am wondering whether or not include the "s". Is art countable or uncountable in this situation? The position oversees the care of artwork (sculpture, painting, ceramics, for example..)

Comment: I was going to reply that it is not really a matter of countable/uncountable, but that _fine arts_ is an established phrase, and _fine art_ isn't, except as a qualifier (eg _fine art photography_). But checking the iWeb corpus, that is not supported very strongly: "Fine arts" has 51948 hits, against 42215 for "fine art".

Comment: *Art* sounds better to me - and the incumbent will be registering / overseeing *fine art*, not *fine arts*.

Answer (score 4):

**They mean different things.**

Specifically 'Fine Art' has two different but related meanings. These are:

1. One of a number of artistic disciplines, such as painting or sculpture
2. The products of the above activities.

The first is countable,  the second is uncountable. So the following are correct:

1. Portrait painting is an example of a fine art.
2. The Mona Lisa is an example of fine art.

So a "Registrar of Fine Arts" acts as Registrar for the departments dealing with the fine arts disciplines.

A "Registrar of Fine Art" deals with works of art.